# Maven/Java build - SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Tags: java, maven

I have the following error after debugging a maven download from nexus in jenkins.

Openssl works ok and the cert is a valid one issued by Amazon.

`BasicRepositoryConnector-nexus.pmc.pearsonprd.tech-2-0, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
09:42:35 %% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
09:42:35 BasicRepositoryConnector-nexus.tech-2-0, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
09:42:35 BasicRepositoryConnector-nexus.tech-2-0, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
09:42:35 BasicRepositoryConnector-nexus.tech-2-0, called closeSocket()
09:42:35 BasicRepositoryConnector-nexus.tech-2-0, called close()
09:42:35 BasicRepositoryConnector-nexus.tech-2-0, called closeInternal(true)
09:42:35`

Maven failed with the following error.

`09:42:35 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hybris-package: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sap:hybris-package:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact com.sap.hybris:hybris-commerce-suite:zip:6.6.0.1 from/to thirdparty (https://nexus.tech/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty): GET request of: com/sap/hybris/hybris-commerce-suite/6.6.0.1/hybris-commerce-suite-6.6.0.1.zip from thirdparty failed: SSL peer shut down incorrectly -> [Help 1]`

My thought process is that its something to do with networking or Java related? Have you seen this before?

Comment: This looks like an SSL error, with the basic error being that an artifact could not be downloaded.  You should look into your connectivity with the artifact repository.

Answer (score 16):

Add the following to your mvn command:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Comment: This solved the problem I was facing, but it would be great with a single line explaining why this is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I am receiving the same error when connected to my employer's VPN although I don't think it's traffic volume related, but rather an issue with TLS renegotiation where a TLS client is supposed to downgrade from TLS1.3 to TLS1.2 if both parties cannot agree on TLS1.3 terms.  I suspect it has something to do with our company's firewall configuration.  Regardless, as listed above, adding -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 fixes the problem when running mvn from the command line, e.g.

```
$ mvn -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 package
```

If you are executing maven through Eclipse, you can add this property as a parameter in the relevant maven run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This frequently happens to me at college where many devices access the maven servers at the same time. So many students are trying to access the dependencies, that the maven servers flag our IP-Addresses as a DOS attack and therefore refuse the connection.

Normally after about 10 Minutes the flag has lifted, and you can access the dependencies again.

If you need the dependencies urgently, try switching your public IP Address (e.g. phone hotspot).

Another long-term solution would be to introduce an artifact store to the network which caches and distributes the dependencies locally and only downloads unknown versions or packages from the maven servers. Talk to your local system administrator about it.

If you are using docker containers in build pipelines then you will need an artifact store, otherwise builds will fail regularly bc of the DOS flag.